# Painting rusty metal

Tags: painting, rust-removal, rust

This is about 8" of metal crown molding that got rusty because water penetrated to it. I fixed the roof leak and am now repairing the inside. What can I do to prime this rusty peace of metal (maybe remove the rust?) so that it gets painted over, preferably with no or little recognition?

[image]

Comment: I would seriously consider removing at least the short section of crown molding in that picture to look at the back side of it. If there's that much rust visible, how much is there behind it? Also, there may be considerable damage to the wall itself. I would also suggest that you consider stripping _all_ the paint off of that metal work and reapplying a new coat. It's lovely work, but the details are beginning to disappear after all the years of repainting without stripping. I know that's a _lot_ of work, which is why nobody else has done it (con't)

Comment: but if you're going to take some of the trim work down to check the back side and the wall, this might be the perfect time to bite the bullet and do it all. That really is a _nice_ ceiling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [rusty metal primer](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/stops-rust/rusty-metal-primer/)s available that will keep the rust from being any kind of problem. It is available in spray and brush on. Typically you will need to wire brush off any loose rust/material and paint it with that primer. After it dries the recommended time, it can be painted over with your color matched finish paint.

Comment: Would be concerned about the wall behind it.  Water seems to have had enough time to rust the metal, probably from behind and it could have done a number on the wall itself.  A small nail pushed into the wall might warrant extra checking.

Comment: The wall at the crown reminded me of a brick pilaster or chimney. If it is that, it should be of no concern. To take down metal trim work such as this is tedious at best, destructive at worst. Bending this stuff is REALLY easy

Comment: That is why I suggested using a small nail to push in first.  If nail goes in easy just below bottom, then more work is needed, even if it is a PITA.

Comment: @crip659, i did all the wall repair, it is visible that just under the rust is unpainted joint compound compared to the green finished wall on the side